# Run a python script on an EC2 instance without uploading the python file to the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

I currently have an EC2 instance running with directories of tenants and files in those directories.  I have to run a python script to go into those directories, find out how much memory each tenant is using, how many files each tenant has, and send that informatin to a grafana dashboard. I have completed the python script and it will go into each tenant, calculate what I need, and send that information to the grafana dashboard if i manually upload the python script to the instance and run it from the command line.

The goal is to automate this process so the script will run every 15 minutes without ever having to upload the python script to the instance. There is a lot of red tape and I am unable to make the script a part of the AMI when the instance is launched, and I haven't found any examples of people trying to do this before.

First of all is what I am trying to do even possible? Ideally I'd like to run the script from a lambda because that would make it very easy to schedule every 15 minutes and my dependencies for the python script would be very easy to put into place. Suggestions have been brought up about using CodeDeploy but I don't know enough about it to know how that would help.

I have created a python script that works and will run on an ec2 instance if it is uploaded and run from the command line, but I haven't been able to run the script "remotely" as I wold like to.

Comment: You can run a Python script on Lambda or any compute you like and have it SSH into the EC2 server and run commands there, using Paramiko. Assuming you have a way to SSH to the EC2 instance. I don't know what you want to do while on the EC2 instance, so this might not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing specific tasks within the EC2 file or memory system, running it as a Lambda is not going to work. Instead look into using SSM to run a remote script on an EC2 instance.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/remotely-run-commands-ec2-instance-systems-manager/

Comment: I've looked into this and to run the script it needs to be uploaded to the EC2 instance and that is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @GrantToenges Why are you trying to "avoid" uploading a script to the instance? What if the script is stored in the `/tmp/` directory? Shells normally want to run a script from a file, so the file needs to be accessible somehow.

Comment: Have to agree with John here, why are you trying to avoid loading a script to a machine. If you have a specific use case or compliance/audit reason then we can understand your needs better.